# How can I e-mail a .csv file in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

In my app, I create a file with a comma-separated array by writing to an OutputStream. Then I want to be able to share this by e-mail so a user can get the data. This is the code I use to create the file:

```
    public String getLogFile(String logName) {
    String path = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "exp " + logName + ".csv";
    Set<Long> keys;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(path);
        Hashtable<Long, Integer> log = (Hashtable<Long, Integer>) dataStorage
                .readObject(logName);
        keys = log.keySet();
        for (Long key : keys) {
            String outString = (key + "," + log.get(key) + "\n");
            System.out.println(outString);
            byte[] buffer = outString.getBytes();
            os.write(buffer);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        AnalyticsService.sendCrashReport(e, "Error writing log", false);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Then, I've created a button that when pressed passes the path of the file to share. I've tried to use MIME types such as "text/plain" and "text/comma-separated-values", but that causes errors. Here is the code executed when the button is pressed.

```
        public void exportLog(String logName) {
        String path = dataBuffer.getLogFile(logName);
        EmailShare email = new EmailShare();
//      email.share("Here is your log.", path, "text/plain");
        email.share("Here is your log.", path, "text/comma-separated-values");
    }
```

When pressed (in the simulator). I get this stack after selecting the dummy e-mail contact to send to:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.scale(JavaSEPort.java:3483)
at com.codename1.ui.Image.scale(Image.java:963)
at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaledImpl(Image.java:933)
at com.codename1.ui.Image.scaled(Image.java:898)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$60.save(JavaSEPort.java:6693)
at com.codename1.share.ShareForm.<init>(ShareForm.java:75)
at com.codename1.share.EmailShare$1$2$1.actionPerformed(EmailShare.java:102)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:455)
at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:358)
at com.codename1.ui.List.fireActionEvent(List.java:1532)
at com.codename1.ui.List.pointerReleasedImpl(List.java:2011)
at com.codename1.ui.List.pointerReleased(List.java:2021)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2560)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3108)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2017)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1065)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:994)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EmailShare` class expects a path to an image file not an arbitrary file as its second argument so loading that fails.

The `Message` class is better suited for that indeed. You can also use the cloud send option which won't launch the native email app. E.g. the `Log` class includes that ability directly thru the `Log.sendLog` API.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the reply. I did discover the Message class and was able to get the desired functionality from it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Messages class is better suited for this task, and should allow attachments, etc.